# tabela dinamica javascript gravar no banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Como eu faço para pegar as inserções da tabela e gravar no banco de dados ?.

Segue meu código.

```js
function addItens () 
{
  // Elemento textarea:
  const texto = $("#texto");  
  // Elemento table:
  const table = $("#products-table");  
  // Divide o conteúdo de textarea em linhas:
  let linhas = texto.val().split("\n");  
  // Percorre todas as linhas:
  for (i in linhas)
  {
    // Verifica se a linha não está vazia:
    if (linhas[i])
    {
      // Divide o conteúdo da linha em colunas:
      let retorno = linhas[i].split(" ");
      
      // Cria uma nova linha na tabela:
      let newRow = $("<tr>");
      
      // Percorre todas as colunas:
      for (j in retorno)
      {
        // Verifica se a coluna não está vazia:
        if (retorno[j])
        {
          // Cria a nova coluna na tabela:
          let newCol = $("<td>");          
          // Adiciona o conteúdo na coluna:
          newCol.html(retorno[j]);        
    // Adiciona a coluna na linha:
          newRow.append(newCol);           
        }
      }
      
      // Cria a coluna de ação:
      let action = $("<td>");      
      // Adiciona a classe "actions":
      action.addClass("actions");  
      // Adiciona a coluna na linha:
      newRow.append(action);
      // Adiciona a linha na tabela:
      table.append(newRow);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s12">
      <textarea id="texto" class="materialize-textarea">
      </textarea>
      <label for="textarea1">Copie e Cole os Dados do Excel</label>
     </div>
         
          <div class="input-field col s12">
       <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="enviar" onclick="addItens()">Enviar</button>
     </div>
          
          <table id="products-table" border="1" class="striped"></table>
```

Obrigada

Comment: você quer salvar o texto ou a tabela formatada? ja pensou em usar o firebase?

Comment: eu quero usar a tabela formatada, nunca tentei rs, meu sistema todo já esta em mysql.

Comment: Então você não quer o valor da tabela, quer a tabela em si, é isso?

Comment: Por favor poste a resposta no campo abaixo, somos um Q&A e em seguida clique em "Publicar sua resposta".

Answer (score 0):

acrescentei no js o seguinte código.

```js
$.post("gravarBanco.php", {retorno:retorno}, function(retorno){         })
```

e fiz o insert pelo arquivo gravarBanco.php dos resultados via POST.

Obrigada.